# ASP.Net 4.5 with DataService: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, dataservice

The Scenario:
I have a simple.Net Solution, with two projects: A website, and a DataService.

I've set the Web.config in both to have the correct (tested) connection strings to my local SQL Server instance.

Upon running (debug) the application, I get the error:

```
Server Error in '/' Application.

No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1:55883

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1:55883

Source Error: 


Line 163:            };
Line 164:
Line 165:            var app = (from a in DbSvcContext.viewApplications
Line 166:                       select new CustomizedApplicationData {
Line 167:                           aId = a.aId,

Source File: c:\Development\mySite\mySite_Admin\mySite.Web\Admin\Applications.aspx.cs    Line: 165 

Stack Trace: 


[SocketException (0x274d): No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1:55883]
   System.Net.Sockets.Socket.DoConnect(EndPoint endPointSnapshot, SocketAddress socketAddress) +208
   System.Net.ServicePoint.ConnectSocketInternal(Boolean connectFailure, Socket s4, Socket s6, Socket& socket, IPAddress& address, ConnectSocketState state, IAsyncResult asyncResult, Exception& exception) +309

[WebException: Unable to connect to the remote server]
   System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse() +6594148
   System.Data.Services.Client.HttpWebRequestMessage.GetResponse() +23
   System.Data.Services.Client.WebUtil.GetResponseHelper(ODataRequestMessageWrapper request, DataServiceContext context, IAsyncResult asyncResult, Boolean handleWebException) +223
   System.Data.Services.Client.QueryResult.ExecuteQuery(DataServiceContext context) +610
   System.Data.Services.Client.DataServiceRequest.Execute(DataServiceContext context, QueryComponents queryComponents) +457
   System.Data.Services.Client.DataServiceQuery`1.Execute() +77
   System.Data.Services.Client.DataServiceQuery`1.GetEnumerator() +13
   System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection) +369
   System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList(IEnumerable`1 source) +58
   mySite.Web.Admin.Applications.GetApplications() in c:\Development\mySite\mySite_Admin\mySite.Web\Admin\Applications.aspx.cs:165
   Sceip.Web.Admin.Applications.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in c:\Development\mySite\mySite_Admin\mySite.Web\Admin\Applications.aspx.cs:151
   System.Web.Util.CalliEventHandlerDelegateProxy.Callback(Object sender, EventArgs e) +51
   System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e) +92
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +54
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +772

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.34009
```

How can I get past this? I need to be able to debug this site, but unless I can get it running, I'm S.O.L..

Answer (score 0):

Generally, this means that something is preventing a connection to this port and the problem is not with your code. You might have a firewall rule in the way, or are trying to run it through a proxy (such as Fiddler) without having the proxy up and running. The easiest way to check would be to disable your firewall and try again. If that doesn't work, try making sure that your browser is not attempting to connect to localhost through a proxy for some bizarre reason. (See [this thread](https://superuser.com/a/505795) as to how you would do that.)

If none of the above applies, try running `netstat -anb` from the command line to see if there's anything listening on the port you were assigned. If you get nothing, try [changing your port number](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178109.ASPX) and see if that works for you. Hope this helps...

Comment: I'd read, I don't know... about 30 or 50 posts about this, the 'answers' to which didn't help me at all. I read your answer, and immediate gave it a whirl - turned my firewall off (livin' on the edge!), and re-ran the app. No dice. Problem persists. So then I went to [link]http://whatismyipaddress.com/proxy-check and checked - No Proxy Detected. I also ran netstat -anb | more (and netstat -aon | more), and nothing was listening. For grins, I changed the port to a few dozen different numbers... no dice.

Comment: I'm [very] new to the Web Services thing, and I'm trying to get a previous developer's code up and running, so this is wandering right up Frustration Avenue for me.

Comment: Hmm... Do you have IIS installed, or do you have an OS on which you can install it? If yes, try having your service run on full fledged ISS and see if that works for you. Alternatively, try uninstalling IIS Express and re-installing the latest version. Have you tried running it from just the plain old VS Development Server? As a last ditch effort if all this fails, try removing your .suo file (it's usually hidden next to your .sln file). If it gets corrupted it can sometimes mess with all sorts of intricate behind the scenes stuff.

Comment: I've got IIS installed. It's IIS 8.5.9600.16384. I've attempted to run the site from IIS instead of Studio, with the same results. I'm trying the uninstall IIS/Ex 8.0 option now to see if that helps. I'll try the .suo option after that.

Comment: So, removing IIS/Ex generates this awesome warning when I open the project in Studio: `"The Web Project 'mySite.DataService' is configured to use IIS Express. You must download and install IIS Express in order to load.`

Comment: Changed the project to run using VSDS instead of IIS/Ex. (I found it in the project properties). Testing that now.

Comment: Ugh. New can of worms. Setting the Web Service and the Website to run in VSDS makes the Web Service XML from WcfDataService.svc open in the browser.

Comment: Restored the project to pre-messing with the Properties. Back to my initial error. (Thank god for Source Control!) Trying the .suo idea next.

Comment: Removing the .suo, restarting VS12, and going Debug, brought me to the same error.

Comment: Wait, wait... When you say "XML from WcfDataService.svc" opens in a browser window, what did you mean? Were you talking about the WSDL or something else?

Comment: It showed me the XML representation of the class. So all of these `config.SetEntitySetAccessRule("Applications", EntitySetRights.All);
            config.SetEntitySetAccessRule("ApplicantInfos", EntitySetRights.All);` get turned into XML tags.

Comment: Can you actually use the service through the browser? Can you test the request you wanted to make and see if it works? Because now I'm thinking that the problem could be your service configuration...

Comment: Nope. It just output some wiggy xml tags. It was very strange.

Comment: There's something wrong with your service then. It should make sure you can run your service in your browser without a client app because if you can't, neither can a client.